# Should the help center rules explictly exclude generic programming questions?

Tags: discussion

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699730) posted on SO that I thought was a good question about general system design practices, as well as being a bit of a request for reassurance.  The question was put on hold and it was pointed out that, since it did not address a specific coding problem, the question was off-topic, which is fair enough.

However, the [help center rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) do say "[...] practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development", and I felt that, as the OP was asking about a practical problem (how to approach system architecture and design) that is most certainly unique to software development, then the rules explicitly consider it to be on-topic.

Should the rules be updated to either be less generic || explicitly exclude general questions that would be better placed in different forums?

Comment: "Practical answerable problems" is a *constraint,* not a broadening of the scope.  The question you linked isn't answerable anyway; even if it were on-topic, it would be too broad.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok.  That's a perspective I hadn't considered, as I felt that it was fairly easy to answer in equally broad terms.  However, my (probably poorly phrased) question here is more about whether the rules on SO should be clearer about generic questions belonging elsewhere, rather than whether the example question was rightly deemed off-topic.

Comment: Centre?  If you check, it is most definitely "Center".  'Murka.